# What is an unsigned char?

Tags: c++, c, char

In C/C++, what an `unsigned char` is used for? How is it different from a regular `char`?

Answer (score 615, accepted):

In C++, there are three *distinct* character types:

1. `char`
2. `signed char`
3. `unsigned char`

#### 1.  `char`

If you are using character types for **text**, use the unqualified `char`:

- it is the type of character literals like `'a'` or `'0'` (in C++ only, in C their type is `int`)
- it is the type that makes up C strings like `"abcde"`

It also works out as a number value, but it is unspecified whether that value is treated as signed or unsigned. Beware character comparisons through inequalities - although if you limit yourself to ASCII (0-127) you're just about safe.

#### 2. `signed char`/ 3. `unsigned char`

If you are using character types as **numbers**, use:

- `signed char`, which gives you *at least* the -127 to 127 range. (-128 to 127 is common)
- `unsigned char`, which gives you *at least* the 0 to 255 range. This might be useful for displaying an octet e.g. as hex value.

"At least", because the C++ standard only gives the minimum range of values that each numeric type is required to cover. `sizeof (char)` is required to be 1 (i.e. one byte), but a byte could in theory be for example 32 bits. **`sizeof` would still be report its size as `1`** - meaning that you *could* have `sizeof (char) == sizeof (long) == 1`.

Comment: To be clear, could you have 32-bit chars, and 32-bit integers, and have sizeof(int) != sizeof(char)? I know the standard says sizeof(char) == 1, but is the relative sizeof(int) based on actual difference in size or the difference in range?

Comment: Joseph, the sizeof gives you the size of the object representation of the type. if you say 32bit int, that first doesn't tell much. most probably you mean the object representation (that's the physical size - including all padding bits).

Comment: if that's the case, then sizeof(int) != sizeof(char) can't be true, because char/unsigned/signed char use all bits of their object representation to represent their values (called the value representation)

Comment: The guaranteed range of `signed char` is -127 to 127, but assuming 2's complement you'll get -128 to 127. And that's a pretty safe assumption.

Comment: how come 1 byte can be 32 bits?

Comment: +1. But there are four distinct character types in C++, wchar_t is one of them.

Comment: @Fruny I noticed that you wrote sizeof () with a space between, can you elaborate the use of that? At the moment, I am searching for answer on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: since c++11 you have 6 distinct types: char, signed char, unsigned char, wchar_t, char16_t, char32_t.

Comment: @pseudonym_127 good question. I think it's because technically size of a bit is unspecified (though commonly it's 8 bits). Hopefully someone else can verify this.

Comment: @unheilig It's common to place a space after `sizeof` because it is not a function but an operator. It is imho even better style to omit the parenthesis when taking the size of a variable. `sizeof *p` or `sizeof (int)`. This makes it clear quickly if it applies to a type or variable. Likewise, it is also redundant to put parenthesis after `return`. It's not a function.

Comment: "`char`: it is the type of character literals like `'a'` or `'0'`." is true in C++ but not C.  In C, `'a'` is an `int`.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, you say "but a byte could in theory be for example 32 bits", but in reality, a byte is 8 bits. What am I missing? Thanks.

Comment: "byte" in this context reffers to the smallest addresable unit of memory. The C and C++ standards require a byte to be at least 8 bits, but they don't specify a maximum. On pretty much all general purpose computers today (including anything that is compliant with recent versions of posix) a byte is exactly 8 bits but specialised DSP platforms and retro systems may have larger bytes.

Comment: Since C++20 you have 7 distinct types. `char` `signed char` `unsigned char` `wchar_t` `char8_t` `char16_t` `char_32_t`

Comment: Regarding @marcinj and @ 김선달's comments, see the 'Character types' part in the [Fundamental types](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types) in cppreference.com.

Answer (score 106):

This is implementation dependent, as the C standard does NOT define the signed-ness of `char`.  Depending on the platform, char may be `signed` or `unsigned`, so you need to explicitly ask for `signed char` or `unsigned char` if your implementation depends on it.  Just use `char` if you intend to represent characters from strings, as this will match what your platform puts in the string.

The difference between `signed char` and `unsigned char` is as you'd expect.  On most platforms, `signed char` will be an 8-bit two's complement number ranging from `-128` to `127`, and `unsigned char` will be an 8-bit unsigned integer (`0` to `255`).  Note the standard does NOT require that `char` types have 8 bits, only that `sizeof(char)` return `1`.  You can get at the number of bits in a char with `CHAR_BIT` in `limits.h`.  There are few if any platforms today where this will be something other than `8`, though.

There is a nice summary of this issue [here](http://www.arm.linux.org.uk/docs/faqs/signedchar.php).

As others have mentioned since I posted this, you're better off using `int8_t` and `uint8_t` if you really want to represent small integers.

Comment: signed char have only a minimum range of -127 to 127, not from -128 to 127

Comment: @12431234123412341234123: Technically true, in that the C standard defines -127 to 127 as the minimum range.  I challenge you to find a platform that doesn't use two's complement arithmetic, though. On nearly every modern platform, the actual range of signed chars will be -128 to 127.

Comment: `CHAR_BIT` is required to be at least 8 bits by the standard.

Answer (score 45):

Because I feel it's really called for, I just want to state some rules of C and C++ (they are the same in this regard). First, *all bits* of `unsigned char` participate in determining the value if any unsigned char object. Second, `unsigned char` is explicitly stated unsigned.

Now, I had a discussion with someone about what happens when you convert the value `-1` of type int to `unsigned char`. He refused the idea that the resulting `unsigned char` has all its bits set to 1, because he was worried about sign representation. But he didn't have to be. It's immediately following out of this rule that the conversion does what is intended:

> If the new type is unsigned, the value is converted by repeatedly adding or subtracting one more than the maximum value that can be represented in the new type until the value is in the range of the new type. (`6.3.1.3p2` in a C99 draft)

That's a mathematical description. C++ describes it in terms of modulo calculus, which yields to the same rule. Anyway, what is *not* guaranteed is that all bits in the integer `-1` are one before the conversion. So, what do we have so we can claim that the resulting `unsigned char` has all its `CHAR_BIT` bits turned to 1?

1. All bits participate in determining its value - that is, no padding bits occur in the object.
2. Adding only one time `UCHAR_MAX+1` to `-1` will yield a value in range, namely `UCHAR_MAX`

That's enough, actually! So whenever you want to have an `unsigned char` having all its bits one, you do

```
unsigned char c = (unsigned char)-1;
```

It also follows that a conversion is *not* just truncating higher order bits. The fortunate event for *two's complement* is that it is just a truncation there, but the same isn't necessarily true for other sign representations.

Comment: Why not just use `UCHAR_MAX`?

Comment: Because `(unsigned type)-1` is some kind of idiom. `~0` isn't.

Comment: if i have something like this `int x = 1234` and `char *y = &x` . Binary representation of `1234 ` is `00000000 00000000 00000100 11010010` . My machine is little endian so it reverses it and store in memory `11010010 00000100 00000000 00000000` LSB comes first. Now Main Part . if i use `printf("%d" , *p)`. `printf` will read first byte `11010010`only the output is `-46` but `11010010` is `210` so why does it print `-46` . I am really confused i guess some char to integer promotion is doing something but i don't know.

Answer (score 33):

As for example usages of *unsigned char*:

`unsigned char` is often used in computer graphics, which very often (though not always) assigns a single byte to each colour component. It is common to see an RGB (or RGBA) colour represented as 24 (or 32) bits, each an `unsigned char`. Since `unsigned char` values fall in the range [0,255], the values are typically interpreted as:

- 0 meaning a total lack of a given colour component.
- 255 meaning 100% of a given colour pigment.

So you would end up with RGB red as (255,0,0) -> (100% red, 0% green, 0% blue).

Why not use a `signed char`? Arithmetic and bit shifting becomes problematic. As explained already, a `signed char`'s range is essentially shifted by -128. A very simple and naive (mostly unused) method for converting RGB to grayscale is to average all three colour components, but this runs into problems when the values of the colour components are negative. Red (255, 0, 0) averages to (85, 85, 85) when using `unsigned char` arithmetic. However, if the values were `signed char`s (127,-128,-128), we would end up with (-99, -99, -99), which would be (29, 29, 29) in our `unsigned char` space, which is incorrect.

Comment: I might be missing something but I don't follow how a fixed shift will break an arithmetic average. The average of 127, -128, and -128 is -43, not -99. If you add 128 to that you get 85 which is the same as your unsigned example.

Answer (score 13):

`signed char` has range -128 to 127; `unsigned char` has range 0 to 255.

`char` will be equivalent to either signed char or unsigned char, depending on the compiler, but is a distinct type.

If you're using C-style strings, just use `char`. If you need to use chars for arithmetic (pretty rare), specify signed or unsigned explicitly for portability.

Comment: how to convert "unsigned char *" to python bytes by use pybind11?

Answer (score 11):

`unsigned char` takes only positive values....like **0** to **255**

where as

`signed char` takes both positive and negative values....like **-128** to **+127**

Answer (score 10):

An `unsigned char` is an unsigned byte value (0 to 255).  You may be thinking of `char` in terms of being a "character" but it is really a numerical value.  The regular `char` is signed, so you have 128 values, and these values map to characters using ASCII encoding.  But in either case, what you are storing in memory is a byte value.

Comment: "The regular char is signed": no, it's implementation dependent. And there's no guarantee that the range of values of an unsigned char is from 0 to 255: it's at least that, but it could be wider.

Comment: `char` is not guaranteed to be a byte.

Comment: @qwr `sizeof(char)` is guaranteed to be 1, as is `sizeof(signed char)` and `sizeof(unsigned char)`. So yes, a `char` is always exactly 1 byte. [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9727465/will-a-char-always-always-always-have-8-bits) a supporting answer. A byte is not always exactly 8 bits (only at least 8 bits), hence the range of an `unsigned char` doesn't have to be 0 to 255. But that's an orthogonal discussion.

Answer (score 10):

`char` and `unsigned char` aren't guaranteed to be 8-bit types on all platforms—they are guaranteed to be 8-bit or larger. Some platforms have [9-bit, 32-bit, or 64-bit bytes](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/intrinsic-types#bits-per-byte). However, the most common platforms today (Windows, Mac, Linux x86, etc.) have 8-bit bytes.

Answer (score 9):

In terms of direct values a regular char is used when the values are known to be between `CHAR_MIN` and `CHAR_MAX` while an unsigned char provides double the range on the positive end. For example, if `CHAR_BIT` is 8, the range of regular `char` is only guaranteed to be [0, 127] (because it can be signed or unsigned) while `unsigned char` will be [0, 255] and `signed char` will be [-127, 127].

In terms of what it's used for, the standards allow objects of POD (plain old data) to be directly converted to an array of unsigned char. This allows you to examine the representation and bit patterns of the object. The same guarantee of safe type punning doesn't exist for char or signed char.

Comment: Actually, it will most often be [-128, 128].

Comment: The standards only formally define the object representation as a **sequence** of `unsigned char`, not an _array_ specifically, & any "conversion" is only formally defined by **copying** from the object to a real, declared _array_ of `unsigned char` & then inspecting the latter. It's not clear whether the OR can be directly reinterpreted as such an array, with the allowances for pointer arithmetic it would entail, i.e. whether "sequence" `==` "array" in this usage. There's a Core Issue #1701 opened in hopes of getting this clarified. Thankfully, as this ambiguity is really bugging me recently.

Comment: @RastaJedi No, it won't. It can't. A range of -128...+128 is physically impossible to represent with 8 bits. That width only supports 2^8 == 256 discrete values, but -128...+128 = 2 * 128 + 1 for 0 = 257. Sign-magnitude representation permits -127...+127 but has 2 (bipolar) zeroes. Two's-complement representation maintains a single zero but makes up the range by having one more value on the negative side; it permits -128...+127. (And so on for both at larger bit widths.)

Comment: Re my 2nd comment, it's reasonable to _presume_ we can take a pointer to the 1st `unsigned char` of the OR and then proceed using `++ptr` from there to read every byte of it... but AFAICT, it's not specifically defined as being allowed, so we're left to infer that it's _'probably OK'_ from lots of other passages (and in many ways, the mere existence of `memcpy`) in the Standard, akin to a jigsaw puzzle. Which is not ideal. Well, maybe the wording will improve eventually. Here's the CWG issue I mentioned but lacked space to link - http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1701

Comment: @underscore_d sorry, that was a typo. [-128, 127] is what I meant to type :p. Yeah, I know about the double zeros ('positive' and 'negative' zero) with sign/magnitude. I must have been tired :p.

Answer (score 8):

`unsigned char` is the heart of all bit trickery. In almost *all* compilers for *all* platforms an `unsigned char` is simply a **byte** and an unsigned integer of (usually) 8 bits that can be treated as a small integer or a pack of bits.

In addition, as someone else has said, the standard doesn't define the sign of a char. So you have 3 distinct `char` types: `char`, `signed char`, `unsigned char`.

Answer (score 7):

If you like using various types of specific length and signedness, you're probably better off with `uint8_t`, `int8_t`, `uint16_t`, etc simply because they do exactly what they say.

Answer (score 4):

Some googling found [this](http://bytes.com/forum/thread61480.html), where people had a discussion about this.

An unsigned char is basically a single byte.  So, you would use this if you need one byte of data (for example, maybe you want to use it to set flags on and off to be passed to a function, as is often done in the Windows API).

Answer (score 4):

An unsigned char uses the bit that is reserved for the sign of a regular char as another number. This changes the range to [0 - 255] as opposed to [-128 - 127].

Generally unsigned chars are used when you don't want a sign. This will make a difference when doing things like shifting bits (shift extends the sign) and other things when dealing with a char as a byte rather than using it as a number.

Answer (score 4):

`unsigned char` takes only positive values: 0 to 255 while
`signed char` takes positive and negative values: -128 to +127.

Answer (score 3):

quoted frome "the c programming laugage" book:

The qualifier `signed` or `unsigned` may be applied to char or any integer. unsigned numbers
are always positive or zero, and obey the laws of arithmetic modulo 2^n, where n is the number
of bits in the type. So, for instance, if chars are 8 bits, unsigned char variables have values
between 0 and 255, while signed chars have values between -128 and 127 (in a two' s
complement machine.) Whether plain chars are signed or unsigned is machine-dependent,
but printable characters are always positive.

Answer (score 2):

`signed char` and `unsigned char` both represent 1byte, but they have different ranges.

```
   Type        |      range
-------------------------------
signed char    |  -128 to +127
unsigned char  |     0 to 255
```

In `signed char` if we consider `char letter = 'A'`, 'A' is represent binary of 65 in `ASCII/Unicode`, If 65 can be stored, -65 also can be stored. There are no negative binary values in `ASCII/Unicode` there for no need to worry about negative values.

**Example**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    signed char char1 = 255;
    signed char char2 = -128;
    unsigned char char3 = 255;
    unsigned char char4 = -128;

    printf("Signed char(255) : %d\n",char1);
    printf("Unsigned char(255) : %d\n",char3);

    printf("\nSigned char(-128) : %d\n",char2);
    printf("Unsigned char(-128) : %d\n",char4);

    return 0;
}
```

**Output -:**

```
Signed char(255) : -1
Unsigned char(255) : 255

Signed char(-128) : -128
Unsigned char(-128) : 128
```

Comment: `char` is not guaranteed to be one byte and `signed char` is only guaranteed to hold range [-127,127] (though almost all systems use two's complement and hold at least [-128,127])

Comment: @awr According to the C standard, `char` is actually defined to be "1 byte", but a byte can be more than 8 bits.