# SQLite C/C++ API unsigned char *

Tags: c++, c, sqlite, char

Why does the SQLite C/C++ API return `unsigned char *`s for text values as opposed to the more de-facto `char *` type?

This is somewhat related to [the unsigned char](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75191/unsigned-char) question, except that the SQLite API's decision seems opposite of the conventional `char *` advice given for string-like values.

For example:

```
const unsigned char *sqlite3_column_text(sqlite3_stmt*, int iCol);
```

Comment: Really?  Can you provide example documentation showing this use of unsigned char *?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the [SQLite documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/capi3ref.html#sqlite3_column_blob):

> (H13821) The sqlite3_column_text(S,N) interface converts the Nth column in the current row of the result set for the prepared statement S into a zero-terminated UTF-8 string and returns a pointer to that string.

UTF-8 wants byte values ranging from 0x00 to 0xFF.  char can range from -0x80 to 0x7F (signed) or 0x00 to 0xFF (unsigned).  Forcing unsigned allows the proper encoding of a UTF-8 string.

Answer (score 9):

At a wild guess I'd say that it has something to do with supporting UTF-8 encoding. Signed char values only make sense in a 7-bit ASCII environment where everything above 0x7f is open to interpretation. In UTF-8 everything between 0x00 and 0xFF can be used equally.

Comment: I also came to this conclusion (sans research).

Comment: I also came to this conclusion (/with/ research; see my answer).

Comment: yes, that's why I upvoted your answer. I did go looking for proof but just didn't have the time.