# c++ how to write integers to a binary file that stay 4 bytes long

Tags: c++

I want to write a bunch of integers to a file and then be able to read them later. My problem is that when I write the integers to a file, smaller integers end up using less than 4 bytes. So 1 for example is represented as 01 rather than 00 00 00 01. This means I'll have trouble reading the file because I don't know where one integer begins and ends. How do I make it so that the integer I write to the file is always 4 bytes long? My code is below:

```
std::fstream file;
file.open("test.bin", std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);
for each(int i in vectorOfInts) {
    file << i;
}
file.close();
```

Comment: Use [`file.write()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/write) then.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why use unsigned chars for writing to binary files? And why shouldn't stream operators be used to write to binary files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7460206/why-use-unsigned-chars-for-writing-to-binary-files-and-why-shouldnt-stream-ope)

Comment: Why do you want to write "00 00 00 01"?

Comment: so that when I read the file I just read 4 bytes at a time to get my desired integer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You seem to be confused between text and binary files. The `<<` operator is used for text files. It converts the value to text and writes that to the file. You need to use the `write` method to write an integer in native binary format to a file. The below would write out the 4 bytes to the file.

```
file.write( reinterpret_cast<const char *>(&i), sizeof(i));
```

You may also need to consider the endianness of data depending on what will be reading the data back.

You could also write the whole vector without a loop using:

```
file.write( reinterpret_cast<const char *>(&vectorOfInts[0]), vectorOfInts.size()*sizeof(int));
```

Comment: ah I see the light now