# How to efficiently save an array of longs to a custom file

Tags: arrays, c, file, file-io, save

I have an array of long values and I would like to save them to a file called "Longs.myData". I expected my file to have a size of 24 bytes since the array only has 3 indices. However, I am getting a file that is 192 bytes. Is there a way to save my data and get a file that takes up 24 bytes? P.S I know that saving the file as a .txt gives a file size of 33 bytes. Thank you!

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>    

void CreateFile()
{
    //Array containing my data
    long data[3];
    data[0] = 2147483644;
    data[1] = 2147483645;   
    data[2] = 2147483646;   
    
    //Initializing a pointer to FILE
    FILE *myFilePointer;
    
    //Creating a new file "Longs.myData"
    myFilePointer = fopen("Longs.myData", "wb");
    
    //Error handling
    if(myFilePointer == NULL){exit(1);}
    
    //Save array to file
    fwrite(data, sizeof(long), sizeof(data), myFilePointer);
    
    //sizeof(long) = 8, sizeof(data) = 24 //Total 192
    printf("%d %d \n", (int) sizeof(long), (int) sizeof(data));
    fclose(myFilePointer);
    
}

int main()
{
    CreateFile();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `fwrite()` will write x items of data, each y bytes in size. `sizeof(data) == sizeof(long)*3`, so you're effectively writing `sizeof(long) * sizeof(long) * 3` bytes to the file, which may or may not segfault.

Comment: This [question / answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17598572/read-and-write-to-binary-files-in-c) address this topic.  Correct me if I am wrong please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this declaration:

```
long data[3];
```

memory for all three elements of `data` is created as one contiguous block.  And per the 2nd and 3rd arguments of the following prototype of [fwrite()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fwrite.htm),

```
size_t fwrite(const void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream)
```

> 2. size − This is the size in bytes of each element to be written.
> 3. nmemb − This is the number of elements, each one with a size of size bytes.

The total number of bytes written is given by multiplying arguments 2 & 3.

So in the following syntax the combined argument are simply representing too many bytes:

```
fwrite(data, sizeof(long), sizeof(data), myFilePointer);
```

Breaking it down...
Total bytes to write are given by

```
sizeof(long)*sizeof(data)
//    8     *    3 * 8  (sizeof(data) == 3 array elements*sizeof(long))
//    8     *      24  = 192
```

1 factor of `sizeof(long)` too many.  If `sizeof(long)` == 8, then the math is:

The arguments can be written several way to get the correct count.  Using `char` (`byte`) as the fundamental element, and given [*sizeof(char)* is always 1](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1-d&q=in+C+is+sizeof%28char%29+always+1%3F):

```
fwrite(data, 1, sizeof(data), myFilePointer);
//           1    3*sizeof(long) ==>  1*3*8   == 24
```

Using `long` as the fundamental element, and the array size (3) as count of elements

```
fwrite(data, sizeof(long), sizeof(data)/sizeof(data[0]), myFilePointer);
//               8                3  ==>  8*3 == 24
```

An aside: although not required, when working with binary files it is preferable to use unsigned types:

> *"unsigned is used to avoid signed [arithmetic] to get in the way, and because it best represents binary contents (a value between 0 and 255)"*

([from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7460206/why-use-unsigned-chars-for-writing-to-binary-files-and-why-shouldnt-stream-ope))