# Cout not printing number

Tags: c++, pointers, printf, cout

### Issue

I'm getting no output from a simple cout, whereas a printf will always print the number:

```
std::cout << variableuint8;  // prints nothing
printf("%u", variableuint8); // prints the number
```

I've never run into this behavior before, and while I have a work around I would like to understand it.

### Context:

Yay, pointers.  So it may be a little more involved than as stated.  Here's the context - I don't think it should matter, by the time cout and printf get the info it's dereferenced to a simple unsigned char.  This is probably more information than needed to resolve the issue, but I wanted to be complete on the off chance that it was relevant.

```
typedef unsigned char   UInt8;
typedef unsigned short  UInt16;

typedef struct{
   UInt8   len;
   // some other definitions. sizeof(DeviceNotification) <= 8
}DeviceNotification;

UInt8 somerandomdata[8];
DeviceNotification * notification;

notification = (DeviceNotification *) somerandomdata;

std::cout << "Len: (" << notification->len << ")\n";
printf("Len: (%u)\n", notification->len);
```

The random data is initialized elsewhere.  For this output, the first byte in the array is 0x08:

#### Output:

```
Len: ()
Len: (8)
```

### Environment

- Development machine:

  - OS X 10.6.8
  - Compiler LLVM 1.7
  - Xcode 3.2.6
- Test machine:

  - OS X 10.6.8

Comment: I just wanna ask is the following line defined in C++? `
notification = (DeviceNotification *) somerandomdata;` doesn't this line invoke undefined behavior if the alignment is not the required alignment of `DeviceNotification`?

Comment: @AraK These are running on x86, which allows unaligned memory accesses.  They may be slower, as they may require two reads of the memory bus to get a value that is split across the boundary, but it works just fine.  You can perform some experiments to demonstrate this - if you do, let us know if there is a speed difference.

Comment: Thanks, that is interesting. It would be nice to write such a micro-benchmark.

Comment: Even on machines that do have strict alignment requirements, these tend to be applied to fundamental types and not structs. In particular, accessing a byte-size member (such as `UInt8 len`) is safe.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's printing the `char` as a character.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
        unsigned char c = 0x41;
        std::cout << c << std::endl;
        return 0;
}
```

This prints 'A' to the stdout.

Although in that case, your code should print `Len: (*)`, and I did have verified it prints `Len: (*)`.

---

Edit: Since in character encodings like ASCII or UTF-8 your console is likely using, the character corresponding to 8 (Backspace) is not visible, it will look like it's not printed.

(In some cases it may cause the previous character (the `(`) to disappear because it is a backspace character. In DOS it may show ◘)

Comment: That's the issue.  You are right about my example output being incorrect - I've changed it to demonstrate the problem as I was actually experiencing it.

Comment: It is not a real point. The example program should print `42` (`*`), but it does not.

Comment: @tyz I made an error in my example - Kenny is correct.  I've modified my example with the actual value I was dealing with.  Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried to cast it into int, to avoid depending on the char type that is used by the implementation:

```
std::cout << (int)variableuint8;
```

Here is an explanation of what is going on: [What is an unsigned char?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75191/what-is-an-unsigned-char/87648#87648)

To get an idea, your implementation is using `unsigned char` as `char`. The ASCII code for 0x08 is the backspace control character, and of course it is not a printable character, that is why you don't see an output in the case of `std::cout`.

Comment: [`std::cout << +variableuint8;`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28414758/995714) would be simpler

Answer (score 3):

Would `std::cout << "Len: (" << (unsigned short)notification->len << ")\n";` print the correct value? I guess casting to an integer is what might be looking for.

Comment: Yes, and this is the correct fix.  In my case I cast `(UInt16)` but the effect is the same.