# How to print hex value of character variables with cout?

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I am studying C++ after learning C language.
When I check inside value of array, I am used to printing hex value of array.
But, I couldn't print hex value of char array with COUT.

```
void Mystr::print(){
    for (int i=0;i<string_length+1;i++){
        cout << hex << string[i];       // 'hex' effects only memcap & string_length value
        printf ("[%x]",string[i]);      // it can print hex value of each character
    }
    cout << endl;
    cout <<"Memcap : " << memcap <<endl;
    cout <<"string length : " << string_length <<endl;
}
```

'cout << hex' can't make an effect on character value. how can I look up hex value of character array with COUT ?

Comment: `cout << hex << static_cast<unsigned>(string[i]);` should do the trick, and I'm sure there is an answer like that already....

Comment: @MatsPetersson _"and I'm sure there is an answer like that already..."_ Found it ;-) ...

Comment: Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14644716/how-to-output-a-character-as-an-integer-through-cout

Comment: Thank you guys, It would be great help to me. I couldn't find similar previous question, Thanks a lot !