# INTtoCHAR function couts wrong value

Tags: c++

here is what my function looks like:

```
signed char INTtoCHAR(int INT)
{
    signed char CHAR = (signed char)INT;
    return CHAR;
}

int CHARtoINT(signed char CHAR)
{
    int INT = (int)CHAR;
    return INT;
}
```

It works properly that it assigns the int value to the char, but when I want to cout that char then it gives me some weired signs. It compiles without errors.

My testing code is:

```
int main()
{
  int x = 5;
  signed char after;
  char compare = '5';
  after = INTtoCHAR(5);

  if(after == 5)
  {
      std::cout << "after:" << after << "/ compare: " << compare << std::endl;
  }


  return 0;
}
```

After is indeed 5 but it doesn't print 5. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you please add the erroneous output?

Comment: It is garbage output @Mikael. However, with my answer, you will get the number.

Comment: @Somebody, can you please confirm that my answer is correct? :)

Comment: @Somebody, you asked for ideas, you got 2, would you care to say something about them? :)

Answer (score 2):

Adding to the above answer using the unary operator `+`, there is another way as well: `typecasting`.

```
std::cout << "after:" << (int)after << "/ compare: " << compare << std::endl;
```

[Correct output](http://ideone.com/4yNedE)

Comment: How didn't I think of that? Nice answer karma_geek! +1

Comment: @gsamaras: I had +1'ed your answer too, because I didn't know about the unary operator method. Thanks to you too :)

Comment: Thanks geek, nice top answer too! ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use `+after` while printing, instead of `after`. This will promote `after` to a type printable as a number, regardless of type.

So change this:

`std::cout << "after:" << after << ", compare: " << compare << std::endl;`

to this:

`std::cout << "after:" << +after << ", compare: " << compare << std::endl;`

For more, see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28414758/2411320).