# Normal variable getting printed but its instance in structure is printing "$"

Tags: c++, data-structures, cout

// function which populates the value of currentTemp and maxTemp

```
  result = smartHlpTemperatureGet( &sh, &currentTemp, &maxTemp );
```

// Adding maxTemp and currentTemp to the structure after gettin

```
diskDataT->currentTemp = currentTemp;
diskDataT->maxTemp = maxTemp;
```

// Following cout is printing the value properly

```
cout<<"Temperatures - Current"<<currentTemp<<"Max Temperature ="<<maxTemp<<endl;
```

//structure in which the above variables are declared

```
  struct diskDataDetailed
{

   uint8_t currentTemp;
   uint8_t maxTemp;

}
```

//Does not print the value of currentTemp

```
cout<<diskDataT->currentTemp<<endl;
```

//Output for above cout

```
$
```

I don't understand where I am going wrong.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to output a character as an integer through cout?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14644716/how-to-output-a-character-as-an-integer-through-cout)

Comment: @AlanStokes does it also apply to structure ? My concern was why the value in the structure is not printing whereas normal variable value is getting printed properly.

Comment: Unless you're storing millions of these it would be easier to use plain `unsigned int` for your values.

Comment: It applies to any value of a `char` type regardless of where you get it from. I bet your variable is not of type `uint8_t`.

Comment: @AlanStokes yeah adding `+` displayed the value in proper format can you help as to how can i populate the structure`diskDataT->currentTemp` with this value

Answer (score 0):

You already have the right value, but because it is of type `unsigned char` (which is  what `uint8_t` is on your system) the default behaviour is to print it as a character not a number.

As I said above replacing `uint8_t` with `unsigned int` would make things slightly easier. Otherwise you just need to remember to convert the value to a wider type before you print it - that's what the `+` does.

Comment: Alan, I agree with you and your solution worked for printing but I wish to know how can i populate the structure with this value I tried this.

` diskDataT->currentTemp = +currentTemp;
   diskDataT->maxTemp = +maxTemp;` but this did not work. I cannot use unsigned int because it is a header file change

Comment: You only need the `+` for output. `diskDataT->currentTemp = currentTemp` is just fine. The problem is not the value or the variable; it is only how you print it. You have to apply the `+` at the time of printing and not before. If you don't want to do that, stop using `uint8_t`.