# Do you use single or double quotes when defining char variables in C++?

Tags: c++, c++14

I have two questions actually

I am trying to do encryption in C++ using the XOR operation. When i encrypt any two characters i get the ? as the encrypted character why is that?

Here is a sample of my code Xoring a and b.

```
#include<iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
int main()
{
    char x='a';
    char y='b';
    char d=x^y;
    cout<<"a xor b = "<<d<<"\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You might want to read a [good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). Also, `char x = "a";` is invalid so your (first) question is moot.

Comment: It seems you are asking one question (which quote do I use) but really wanting to ask another (why does xor-ing two characters not give the result I want). Consider [edit]ing your question to clarify your actual question

Comment: What output did you expect for this program?

Comment: I expect to get different answers when xoring different characters but i get the same answers for almost xoring any two different characters

Comment: `'a' == 0x61`, `'b' == 0x62`. Hence `x ^ y` produces 3 which is a [control character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Control_characters) and not printable

Answer (score 3):

When you output characters which are not printable (and below the 'space' which is 32, most of them are) you are getting question mark or square depending on where you do it. To see the integer value of the XOR, replace `d` with `(int)d`

Comment: or simply use [`cout << +d`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14644716/995714)

Comment: Space is not always 32. In addition to being the final frontier, it's actual value depends on the character encoding being used.

Comment: @user4581301, indeed, space depends on locale, however, in the example present no one called std::setlocale(), so default one is classic ASCII with the space 32 and control characters 0-31.