# How to print signed char to cout as number under Android

Tags: android, c++, cout

I'm trying to redirect a signed char to cout. It works fine under Windows/VS2019 thanks to [How to output a character as an integer through cout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14644716/how-to-output-a-character-as-an-integer-through-cout).

However, under Android, compiled with CLang, it does not behave as expected.

Here is the code:

```
char c = -1;
std::cout << "c signed is " << signed(c) << std::endl;
std::cout << "+c is " << +c << std::endl;
```

Under Windows, I get expected output:

```
c signed is -1
+c is -1
```

Under Android, I get expected output:

```
c signed is 255
+c is 255
```

What portable code would help displaying "-1" on all platform?

Comment: It's implementation defined if `char` is signed or unsigned. On your computer it seems to be signed, while on Android it seems to be unsigned. If you want an explicit signed 8-bit integer then use `int8_t`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that and let you know

Comment: Refer to [Is char signed or unsigned by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2054939/is-char-signed-or-unsigned-by-default)

Comment: Note that `signed()` casts to `signed int`, not to `signed char`. `signed int` can hold both `255` and `-1`, so you will always see the value that is really stored in `char`. Try `static_cast<signed char>(c)` to always see `-1`.

Answer (score 0):

As commented by *Yksisarvinen*, *Some programmer dude* and *Sander De Dycker*, the problem does not come from the way `c` is redirected to the stream, but more from `c`'s type itself. Using `char` should be avoided if you expect the variable to be signed, because `char` is not necessarily signed.

The problem is fixed by using `int8_t` or `signed char` instead of `char`.