# C++ type unsigned long int

Tags: c++, c

Is  `unsigned long int`  equivalent to `unsigned long`
in C++?

In my opinion they are same. But I've seen some people still using `unsigned long int` in code and I don't understand why. Here is a sample code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    unsigned long int num = 282672; 
    int normalInt = 5;
    printf("");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 27):

## Yes.

`long` is just a shorthand for `long int`. This is because in principle `long` is just a qualifier (it can also be used for prolonging a `double` datatype, for example)

From C++ ISO Standard, section 7.1.5.2, a table of equivalent type specifiers:

[image]

Comment: I see that in your table every type omits the `signed` token, except for chars. Is this intentional or is this a mistake in the table?

Comment: Nope, that's no mistake. See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/2054941/478658 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/87648/478658

Comment: @RikSchaaf -  No it is not a mistake.   The standards specify that it is implementation defined whether `char` is a `signed` or `unsigned` type.  And, in fact, `char` is actually a distinct type from both `unsigned char` and `signed char`.   This is different from all other integral types, which are `signed` unless the `unsigned` keyword is used.

Comment: @Sebastian Interesting to know. I read a bit through the answers and comments of the 2 questions to see the reason why both exist. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 4):

§6.7.2 of the C99 standard gives the following list of types (this is only an excerpt):

- `short`, `signed short`, `short int`, or `signed short int`
- `unsigned short`, or `unsigned short int`
- `int`, `signed`, or `signed int`
- `unsigned`, or `unsigned int`
- `long`, `signed long`, `long int`, or `signed long int`
- `unsigned long`, or `unsigned long int`
- `long long`, `signed long long`, `long long int`, or `signed long long int`
- `unsigned long long`, or `unsigned long long int`

with the following additional point:

> (5) Each of the comma-separated sets designates the same type, except that for bit-fields, it is implementation-defined whether the specifier `int` designates the same type as `signed int` or the same type as `unsigned int`.

Comment: Though this is a C++ question ;)

Comment: Yes, C++ question with code that includes `stdio.h` and uses `printf` ;)

Comment: Right :P Sometimes, I look at just the tags, sometimes at just the code, and fall prey to this, too :D

Comment: The question is tagged both C and C++ anyway.

Comment: It wasn't initially. The C tag was added more than a year later.

Answer (score 1):

*Yes*. `unsigned`, `signed`, `short`, `long`, `long long` all are simple type specifiers for `XXX int`.

See *7.1 Specifiers [dcl.spec]* in the standard:

> 3 [ Note: Since signed, unsigned, long, and short by default imply int, a type-name appearing after one of
>   those specifiers is treated as the name being (re)declared. [ Example:
>
> `void h(unsigned Pc); // void h(unsigned int)`
>
> `void k(unsigned int Pc); // void k(unsigned int)`
>
> —end example ] —end note ]

and *7.1.6.2 Simple type specifiers [dcl.type.simple]*

```
    Table 10 — simple-type-specifiers and the types they specify

    Specifier(s)            | Type
    ------------------------+---------------------------------
    type-name               | the type named
    simple-template-id      | the type as defined in 14.2
    char                    | “char”
    unsigned char           | “unsigned char”
    signed char             | “signed char”
    char16_t                | “char16_t”
    char32_t                | “char32_t”
    bool                    | “bool” 
    unsigned                | “unsigned int”
    unsigned int            | “unsigned int”
    signed                  | “int”
    signed int              | “int”
    int                     | “int”
    unsigned short int      | “unsigned short int”
    unsigned short          | “unsigned short int”
    unsigned long int       | “unsigned long int”
    unsigned long           | “unsigned long int”
    unsigned long long int  | “unsigned long long int”
    unsigned long long      | “unsigned long long int”
    signed long int         | “long int”
```

Answer (score 0):

`unsigned long int` is the correct type definition, however `int` can be ignored.

Comment: As are `long unsigned` and `int long unsigned`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they are the same. Saying `unsigned long int` is simply explicitly stating that it is an int.

You can always look at the size of the type by `sizeof(unsigned long int)` and `sizeof(unsigned long)`

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "explicitly stating that it is an int". `unsigned long int` and `int` are two distinct types. `int` is both a keyword and the name of a type; the name `unsigned long int` uses the keyword `int`, but does not refer to the type `int`.