# C++ information about placing a small integer in a char

Tags: c++, char

I see a lot of code in C++ where they use `char` to represent numbers smaller
than 256.

Should these be `unsigned char` instead of `char`?

What happens if I do this?

```
char t = 255;
```

I remember I read at some place that saying char is special about the signs.

Comment: May be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2054939/char-is-signed-or-unsigned-by-default

Comment: Yes, there's no guarantee whether that will fit or not.

Comment: Dupe: What is an `unsigned char` and how is it different from a `char`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/75191/what-is-an-unsigned-char

Answer (score 2):

`char` is a distinct type from the signed and unsigned versions, and may be signed or unsigned. If you want a specifically signed or unsigned byte/char, you should indeed specify that in your variable declaration.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `char` can be signed or unsigned [basic.fundamental], it's up to the compiler ("C++ implementation") to choose(*). If it's signed, there's no guarantee it can hold the value `255`, and in the case it cannot hold the value `255`, the conversion results in an implementation-defined value [conv.integral].

As `unsigned char` is guaranteed to have at least 8 bits (as well as `char` and `signed char`), the line `unsigned char t = 255;` is fine.

<sub>(*) That does **not** mean `typedef signed char char;`, as `char`, `signed char` and `unsigned char` are required to be three distinct types [basic.fundamental]/1.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking, it depends on how many bits there are in a `char` for the target in question.  You're right that for a normal 2's complement machine with a signed 8-bit `char` type, that they should probably be using `unsigned char`.

The conversion from signed to unsigned, should one take place, is well-defined according to the C++ spec (**4.7 Integral conversions**):

> 2 If the destination type is unsigned, the resulting value is the least unsigned integer congruent to the source integer (modulo 2<sup>*n*</sup> where *n* is the number of bits used to represent the unsigned type). [*Note:* In a two’s complement representation, this conversion is conceptual and there is no change in the bit pattern (if there is no truncation). *—endnote*]

The conversion from unsigned to signed, however, is implementation-defined:

> 3 If the destination type is signed, the value is unchanged if it can be represented in the destination type (and bit-field width); otherwise, the value is implementation-defined.

But in practice, most systems work they way you'd expect and things go fine.  That is, signed overflow works like unsigned overflow, the bit patterns don't change regardless of signed->unsigned or unsigned->signed conversions, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The standard doesn't specify if plain 'char' is signed or unsigned.  It's left up to the compiler.  In GCC it's signed by default, but can be specified with `-funsigned-char/-fsigned-char` and likewise in MSVC the default is signed but can be forced to unsigned with `/J`.

Comment: It's not correct.  gcc will default char to signed or unsigned based on the target architecture/abi.  On most, it will be signed.  On others such as ppc (on most unices), it will be unsigned.