# character as integers in C programming language

Tags: c, compiler-construction

Can character be classified as an integer in C language.

I am talking in context of a lexical analyzer.I am building a scanner using C language.

Comment: it depends on sizeof(integer) and sizeof(char).

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is an unsigned char?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/75191/what-is-an-unsigned-char)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do:

```
const char str[] = "Hello world";
char c = 'H';

// And use any of these:
int chr = 'H'; // chr = 0x48
chr = c; // chr = 0x48
chr = str[0]; // chr = 0x48
```

And you'll always end up having `0x48` (72) in `chr`.

Comment: Not always. Not all C implementations use ASCII.

Comment: @EricPostpischil can you be more specific? I'm curious where it'll get another result.

Comment: EBCDIC is not dead yet, and a compiler for an embedded system could make up its own character encoding.

Comment: @EricPostpischil oh, that charset table (characters not grouped together but having spaces between `i` and `j`, `r` and `s`) looks terrible to me (but I assume there's historical reason for it). So what formulation do you suggest? Perhaps "*at least on linux and windows platforms*"?

Comment: The EBCDIC character codes are influenced by the available positions for holes on [Hollerith punched cards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punched_card). The characters step through punches in rows 1-9, then change one of the other rows, then step again. Simply write “The value of `'H'` is the numeric code for the character “H” in the execution character set, which is 72 in ASCII (the most commonly used character set).” You cannot qualify this by Linux or Windows platform, because anybody may write a C implementation for those platforms that does not use ASCII.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you want to ask if char can be classified as `numbers`. If so, yes they can, as char variables stores the value of a char as a number.

Say:

```
char c = 120; //legal
```

The range of the numbers you can store in a char depends on the compiler. Most commonly, char variables stores values of a range from `-128` to `127`, total 256 possibilities.

As per [Variables. Data Types. - C++ Documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/variables/)

You can also work with unsigned chars, that goes from `0` to `255`.

Please realize that if you store a number out of this range you will lose precision. Say:

```
char c = 300;
int i = c;
std::cout << i;   //prints 44
system("pause");
return 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

In "**The C Programming Language**" (second edition) it is specifically mentioned that there is no distinction between char and int types as far as character manipulation functions of *stdio.h* are concerned.

> The type char is specifically meant for storing (such) character data,
>   but any integer type can be used

This is an example adapted from the book and illustrating this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
/* copy input to output */
int
main(void)
{
  int c;
  while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    putchar(c);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course, charactor can be implicitly converted to an integer.

```
char a = 'c';
int b = a;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using TypeCasting:

```
char c = 'a';
int x = (int) c;
printf("%d\n", c);
```

OR

```
char c = 'a';
printf("%d\n", c);
```

Both will give you 97

Comment: No need to cast `c`. The value of `c` is simply the ASCII-value of `a`, which is a digit.

Comment: yup.. thats why i provided OR statement.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Characters are represented as integers. One common pitfall when analysibng input is shown below:

```
char c; // (!!) should be of type int to hold EOF

while((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`char` is an integer type like `int` with a reduced range.

You can add, multiply, shift, print, scan as you would with `int`, `short`, `long` or `long long`.  `char` has a smaller range than the others.  Much code involving `char` and `short` silently promote to `int`, so care is needed.

```
char c;
int i;

c = -2; // OK
i = -2; // OK

// sizeof(c) == 1
// sizeof(i) >= 2  (often 4, sometimes 8)

scanf("%hhd", &c);
scanf("%d", &i);

printf("%hhd", c);
printf("%d", i);
```

---

On exotic machines where a `byte` is > 9 bits, additional issues apply.