# C: char vs. unsigned char for non-ASCII text data

Tags: c, string, unsigned-char

This question:

[What is an unsigned char?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75191/what-is-an-unsigned-char)

does a great job of discussing *char* vs. *unsigned char* vs. *signed* char in C.

However, it doesn't directly address what should be used for non-ASCII text.  Thus if I have an array of bytes that represents text in some arbitrary character set like UTF-8 or Big5 (or sometimes ASCII), should I use an array of *char* or *unsigned char*?

I'm leaning towards using *char* because otherwise gcc gives me warnings about signedness of pointers when the array is ASCII and I use *strlen*.  But I would like to know what is correct.

Comment: Yes, the accepted answer is correct in that regard. And the C string-type is a sequence of non-NUL bytes terminated by a NUL-byte, of unspecified encoding, though use UTF-8 if you have any choice at all.

Comment: Except for UTF-8, you don't want to use strlen because there can be internal NULs. Anyway, this is a huge topic. For Unicode I suggest http://site.icu-project.org/

Comment: @Deduplicator Please read more carefully: **Except for** UTF-8, ... there can be internal NULs. And what I meant is what the OP referred to: Big5 etc. Of course UTF-16 and UTF-32 can also contain internal NULs, so yes, what I wrote applies to them *to*.

Comment: @JimBalter: Do you know an 8bit-encoding with internal `NUL`s which are not that terminator?

Comment: An advantage of `unsigned char` over `char` (when `char` is signed) is with `is...()` functions which are UB for `signed char` as they expect a `unsigned char` or EOF.

Comment: @PetrAbdulin NUL is an ASCII character 0. Since UTF-16 is non-ASCII it cannot have NUL by definition.  It can't have zero characters either.   (It can have subsets of 8 zero bits in a row but that doesn't matter)

Comment: Craig, if the data is mixed of text and non-text you have to pick whichever option ends up in less casting :)

Comment: @JimBalter my bad, misread you, sorry.

Comment: @Matt McNabb Would you also say "Since EBCDIC is non-ASCII it cannot have NUL by definition"? Hopefully not since it's patently absurd. By NUL here, we mean '\0', which isn't restricted to ASCII -- nor is the standard C language, and therefore strlen etc. The warning about internal NULs/zero bytes in UTF-16, UTF-32, and other string encodings is legitimate because it may not be obvious to people who don't know everything there is to know about string encodings. A much longer discussion would cover wcslen etc. (and why those, too, can't be used with Unicode encodings.)

Comment: Chux - I see that _isalpha()_ and its cousins expect an _int_ (FreeBSD 8.4 man page, MKS web page, others) not an _unsigned int_.  So...could you clarify?  What does **UB** mean?

Comment: @chux: The `is*()` functions do not have undefined behavior for `signed char` arguments. They have undefined behavior if the argument (which is of type `int`) is not within the range of `unsigned char` or equal to `EOF`. `isalpha((char)'A')` is well defined; `isalpha((char)-42)` has undefined behavior.

Comment: OP,  Note: Suggest using @ + "user" to insure timely notification  as in "@chux" vs "Chux".  Hopefully @Keith Thompson cleaner explanation answers your comment.  -- Unclear why "not an _unsigned int_." mentioned.

Answer (score 4):

Use normal char to represent characters. Use signed char when you want a signed integer type that covers values from `-127 to +127` . Use unsigned char for having an unsigned integer type that has range of values from `0 to 255` .

Comment: Technically `uint8_t` should be used for the latter (which will give a compiler error if you're on a platform that doesn't support 8-bit chars)

Comment: This doesn't say anything more (and quite a bit less) than the link that the OP provided. i.e., it isn't an answer to the question asked and doesn't even reflect that there was such a question. It's stunning that it got two upvotes.

Answer (score 2):

The question you are asking is probably much broader that you expect.

To answer it directly, most implementations use "byte" as underlying buffer. In that terms standard `uint8_t` typedef is your best bet. That is primarily because most character sets use variable number of bytes to store characters, so separate byte processing is essential in encoding and decoding process. It also simplifies conversion between different "endianess".

In general it's incorrect to use `strlen` on anything other than ASCII encoding or other single-byte code pages (0-255 range). It's certainly incorrect on any multi-byte encoding like Big5, UTF-8/16 or Shift-JIS.

Comment: How is `strlen()` any less safe on UTF-8 vs. ASCII?  Both has a code 0.  C simple uses code 0 (ASCII NUL) as a terminating character, thus disallowing a C string with ASCII NUL characters.  Code could equally use Unicode 0 (encoded in UTF-8 as a single 0 byte) as a terminating character.  Not that I favor 0 terminated strings, but do not see a great concern using `strlen()` on a string-like group of UTF-8 encoded Unicode characters.

Comment: @chux UTF-8 is not a single byte character encoding. It will report incorrect number of characters. Maybe "safe" was not a best word.

Comment: True that `strlen()` will not report the number of Unicode characters , but will safely report the correct number of `char` used in the UTF-8 encoding assuming a 0 termination.

Comment: @chux you are correct. My main point was that using `strlen` on mbcs is a bad idea in general. Usually we expect that `strlen` return number of characters, not number of bytes used.

Comment: It would be better to talk here about strcpy, which *can* be used on multi-byte encodings as long as they can't have internal '\0'.

Answer (score 0):

As far as UTF8 or any encoding where ASCII characters have the same codepoints, `char` is the best type for multi-byte characters string:

assume `typedef char utf8`:

**This is the only way to allow `char *` to be used as `utf8 *` without an explicit cast. This is extremely common and a good enough reason to be better than `unsigned char`.**

`utf8 *` could be accidentally passed to function expecting a pointer to a sequence of ASCII characters, but this could also be needed if you need to printf your utf8 string (which is a valid thing to do)

The main drawback is that as `char` sign is unknown, **usage of arithmetic operators like `>` is unsafe**, and the only safe way to check if a character is in the ASCII range is by checking the bit directly with `ISASCII(c) ((c & (1 << 7) == 0)`