# Why the loop becomes infinite?

Tags: c++

How to get out of an infinite loop?

```
unsigned char half_limit = 130;

for (unsigned char i = 0; i < 2 * half_limit; ++i)
{
    //smth is happening;
}
```

Help, please.

Thank you!

Comment: `break`, but I can't see any infinite loop.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 4):

Make your loop variable an `int`.

`unsigned char` can't exceed 255, so incrementing `i` past that will wrap it to 0.

`2*130` is 260, because the type of literal `2` is `int`, and multiplying an `int` by `unsigned char` you get an `int`.

Thus, when `i` is an `unsigned char`, your loop termination condition will never be satisfied since `i` will always be less than 260, hence the infinite looping.

Answer (score 1):

> How to get out of an infinite loop?

Paradoxically, you cannot. Because if you get out of a loop, then the loop was finite.

Comment: Why y'all downvoting this answer. It is correct.  Honestly, this question is bad.

Comment: @Daniel this answer is technically correct, but misses the spirit of the question. The asker is obviously a beginner, and may be lacking in terminology, or may not be a native english speaker. This would be better as a clarifying comment or question under the main question. We can all take a moment to laugh at the cleverness of this non-answer, but it does little to help OP.

Comment: @John `it does little to help OP` I disagree. It is arguably more useful to learn the language, terminology and the philosophy around the puzzle than to be merely told the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you take a look at this post:

[What is an unsigned char?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75191/what-is-an-unsigned-char)

Or you could try this approach:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
        int half_limit = 130;
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < 2 * half_limit; ++i){
                printf("%d\n", i);
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As `i` is of type `unsigned char` which is of size 1byte and can hold 0 to 255 values.
If you increment `i` after 255 (i.e 0xFF) expectation is `i` to become 256 but `i` hold value 0 due overflow. (i.e in 256 is equivalent to 0x100 and only lower byte value will be available in `i`)

In order to run loop from 0 to 260 you need to change the type of `i` which can hold value beyond 255.

`short int` or `int` is preferable,

```
unsigned char half_limit = 130;

for (int i = 0; i < 2 * half_limit; ++i)
{
    //smth is happening;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're having an infinite loop because of `unsigned char` range which is from 0 to 255. So basically, `i` never reaches `2 * half_limit`. `i` starts from 0 then goes to `255` then goes to `0` again and so on and so forth.