# Special character in char arrays

Tags: c

I'm trying to retrieve some text from a char array, like this:

```
unsigned char some_variable[3][10] = {"text1","text2","text3"};

int i;

for(i=0;i<3;i++){
    functionIcantChange(some_variable[i])
}
```

I'm getting this issue since this functionICantChange takes aguments like "hello" and "world" with **"** characters included. And by calling for example some_variable[0] I just get **text1** for example.

I need to add the **"** character to the array before passing the array to the function. How could I do this?

Comment: This should be `char* some_variable[] = { ... }`.

Comment: If you want quotes in your string: `"Say \"hello\""`.

Comment: Recursively? Where's the recursion?

Comment: I need something like unsigned char variable[1][10]={""text1""} so variable[0] returns "text1" instead of text1

Comment: By the way, you should use `char` to represent characters, not `unsigned char`.

Comment: @Ariel my answer below does that...  Not sure if that's what you mean,   -- Also recursive is a bit confusing.

Comment: @jarmod *By the way, you should use `char` to represent characters, not `unsigned char`*  Yes, it's OT, but can you explain why?

Comment: @AndrewHenle good discussion here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75191/what-is-an-unsigned-char. Additionally here: https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/c/STR04-C.+Use+plain+char+for+characters+in+the+basic+character+set

Comment: @IlanKeshet It was my fault, this snippet doesn't use anything recursively. I removed it from the question. And yeah, your answer is what I wanted to, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you use sprintf to insert quotations in the front and back of your array.  You would need some large buffer to hold the value of the variable.

```
char buffer[255];
sprintf(buffer, "\"%s\"", some_variable[i]);
functionIcantChange(buffer);
```

Comment: I recommend forget `sprintf` - use `snprintf`.

Answer (score 0):

> I need something like unsigned char variable[1][10]={""text1""} so variable[0] returns "text1" instead of text1

Escape the quotes.

```
char some_variable[3][10] = {"\"text1\"","\"text2\"","\"text3\""};
```

See [cppreference escape sequences](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/escape).

Comment: I agree that's a possible solution too... but I wasn't sure if his "some_variable" was allowed to be modified