# Compare UTF-8 characters

Tags: c++, linux, unicode, utf-8

Here is a parsing function:

```
double transform_units(double val, const char* s)
{
    cout << s[0];
    if (s[0] == 'm') return val * 1e-3;
    else if (s[0] == 'µ') return val * 1e-6;
    else if (s[0] == 'n') return val * 1e-9;
    else if (s[0] == 'p') return val * 1e-12;
    else return val;
}
```

In the line with 'µ' I'm getting the warning:

```
warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]
```

and the character 'µ' is not being catched.

How to compare multibyte characters?

Edit: a dirty workaround is to check if it is less than zero. As Giacomo mentioned, it's `0xCE 0xBC`, both these bytes are greater than 127, so less than zero. It works for me.

Comment: Compare them as strings, not as individual characters. `µ` doesn't fit in a single `char`, as the warning says. In UTF-8, it is 2 chars `0xC2 0xB5`

Comment: or `0xCE 0xBC` (Greek mu letter), so you may need to normalize

Comment: C++ has the [char8_t](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types#char8_t) type for UTF8 characters and strings. You can specify UTF8 characters and literals with the `u8` prefix, eg `u8'μ'`,`u8'm'`. If you use the correct type you'll be able to compare characters directly. [UTF8 string literals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) are available singe C++11 so even if your compiler doesn't support `char8_t`, you'll be able to use `u8'μ'`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos "you'll be able to use u8'μ'" That's [not true](https://godbolt.org/z/9KrjWaYh9).

Comment: There is no such thing as a UTF-8 character. UTF-8 is a variable-length encoding of Unicode characters. Each Unicode character is encoded as a sequence of bytes. In order to compare byte sequences, you compare byte sequences, not individual bytes. A byte sequence in C++ is normally represented as a character array.

Comment: The edit mention a sign-test: don't. That is not portable as 'char' in a different implementation may be unsigned; (see e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75191/what-is-an-unsigned-char )

Comment: @HansOlsson this is why I've called it dirty :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to compare multibyte characters?

You can compare a unicode code point consisting of multiple bytes (more generally, multiple code units) by using multiple bytes. `s[0]` is only a single `char` which is the size of a byte and thus cannot by itself contain multiple bytes.

This may work: `std::strncmp(s, "µ", std::strlen("µ")) == 0`.

Comment: Note that this depends on how you save the source file (i.e., which encoding you use).